# fetch data from url in monotouch

Tags: iphone, ipad, url, syntax, xamarin.ios

i am new to `iPad` developer,

i have created two or three `iPad` application in objective c using `Xcode 4.`

but now i want to create `iPad` application using `Monodeveloper` tool in `C#` language...

in which, i want to fetch data from `url`,

how should i fetch data from url and store it in string.

i searched in google but i didn't got any syntax.

*Any help will be appreciated.*

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://abc.com"); 
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); 
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at WebClient:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient ()) {
    Console.WriteLine (wc.DownloadString (url));
}
```

Comment: +1 `WebClient` requires less code (the other sample does not deal with `IDisposable` streams, requests and responses) and can be easily set to work **asynchronously**.